# Get Latest Gmail Attachment from Labeled Thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to get the latest attachment of the latest message of a thread in gmail through google apps script. Here is what I have:

```
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SpecificLabel');
  var threads = label.getThreads();     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  //message.reverse

  var attachment = message[threads[0].getMessageCount()-1].getAttachments()[0];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var summarySht = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var dbPullSht = ss.getSheetByName('Database Pull');

  Browser.msgBox(attachment.getContentType());
  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  if (attachment.getContentType() === 'text/csv') { 
     //do something
  }
```

I've tried to reverse the message with the code I commented out. That didn't seem to work. Currently the message box will state that the attachment is an image. I think it's accessing the correct message of the correct thread but it is pulling an image the sender has in their signature.

This is how it works. I send an xls file to someone. They send back a CSV file. I need that CSV file.

Comment: @I'-'I I can do that but there is no guarantee it is coming from the same person, or that the next person will have the same number of images if any. Also, I did that to see what the file type was and it returned `application/octet-stream`. Does this sound familiar to you? I was expecting `text/csv`.

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks. I have added a loop to check for the file name and that is working. Just have to ensure the filename does not change.

Comment: Note that SO should not be treated as an interactive "let's address my work task in total" session - you should ask a single, well-researched question and show what you have tried to achieve, how you tried, and what prevented it from being achieved. You should edit your question and its title to reflect your specific issue.

Comment: @tehhowch understood. My question did not change and was addressed. The question at the end is more of a "be aware" to those who stumble on this question. I will either be ensuring that the filename and filetype do not change or coding to take that into consideration. I don't expect that to be answered, but I understand how you came to that. I'll delete that.

Comment: @I'-'I Will do. Makes sense to give it closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a for-loop to get the attachment with the correct name. **This assumes that the file name will be the same.**

```
//gets first(latest) message with set label
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SpecificLabel');
var threads = label.getThreads(0, 1);
var message = threads[0].getMessages();
message = message[message.length - 1];
var attachments = message.getAttachments();
for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
  if (attachments[i].getName() === 'filename.csv') {
    var attachment = attachments[i];
  }
}
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var summarySht = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
var dbPullSht = ss.getSheetByName('Database Pull');

Browser.msgBox(attachment.getContentType());
Browser.msgBox(attachment.getName());
// Does the attachment name match?
if (attachment.getName() === 'filename.csv') {
  //do something
}
```

This will also do a check for the name of the file instead of the filetype before continuing with the code.